# how do i present or push a view controller from app action extension to the my app in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have added an app action extension (name: Example Extension) and i am accessing that in photos,

[image]

So when i click on share, this screen will be appearing:

[image]

From that i am selecting my action extension, Example Extension, then i would be getting my screen like this:

[image]

So, when i click on Add item, then i must push or present my custom app Extension with the image that we are seeing, i can save the image, that is not a problem, but the main thing is, i need to push or present my app from this app extension, how it can be done, please share the code with neat explanation, thanks in advance.